# JBoss mutual certificate authentication fails on SSL Handshake

Tags: ssl, jboss, certificate, mutual-authentication

I followed all the steps in this blogpost http://virgo47.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/tomcat-web-application-with-ssl-client-certificates/ except for the fact that I'm using JBoss7.0.2 and not the 6.x version.

The goal is to ask any clients to provide a client certificate and achieve mutual authentication between the client and the server.

I have created a certification authority (CA) to sign the client and server certificates.

I have imported the server certificate into the keystore and added an HTTPS connector to the standalone.xml configuration file to serve HTTPS requests on the 8443 port.

I have imported the CA root certificate into the Certificate Manager under Authorities in client's Firefox.

Everything works fine and when I request https://localhost:8443 I get a page with a valid server certificate.

The problem is, when I import the client certificate into the Certificate Manager in Firefox and set the server configuration to verify client certificates (verify-client="true" in standalone.xml) I get a browser error:

```
Secure Connection Failed:
An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8443.
SSL peer cannot verify your certificate.
(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_alert)
```

while the jboss log on the server states:

```
11:01:31,142 DEBUG [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8443-1) Handshake failed: java.io.IOException: SSL handshake failed. Ciper suite in SSL Session is SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.handshake(JSSESocketFactory.java:191) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.setSocketOptions(JIoEndpoint.java:1144) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_30]
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem?

My setup:

Localhost server:

```
sovo@sovo-pc:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 10.10
```

JBoss 7.0.2 Final standalone.xml (relevant parts):

```
<management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="PropertiesMgmtSecurityRealm">
            <authentication>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
    <management-interfaces>
        <native-interface interface="management" port="9999"/>
        <http-interface interface="management" port="9990"/>
    </management-interfaces>
</management>
<profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.0">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Disabled" flag="required"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0" default-virtual-server="default-host">
        <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="https" scheme="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
            <ssl name="ssl" key-alias="sercer" password="changeit" certificate-key-file="/usr/share/jboss7.0.2/standalone/configuration/certificates/keystore.jks" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="true" ca-certificate-file="/usr/share/jboss7.0.2/standalone/configuration/certificates/cacerts.jks"/>
        </connector>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
</profile>
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:localhost}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public">
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="jmx-connector-registry" port="1090" interface="management"/>
    <socket-binding name="jmx-connector-server" port="1091" interface="management"/>
    <socket-binding name="jndi" port="1099"/>
    <socket-binding name="osgi-http" port="8090" interface="management"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Java version:

```
sovo@sovo-pc:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_30"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_30-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.5-b03, mixed mode)
sovo@sovo-pc:~$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_30
```

I'll be happy to provide other relevant information if needed.

Comment: I have reported this issue as a bug to jboss.org. In the meantime, I have downgraded to jboss-6.1.0, where everything works as expected.

Comment: No updates on that previous bug report, but I tried the JBoss 7.1.0 version and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give a try by adding cipher suite you your ssl connector:

```
<ssl name="ssl" key-alias="sercer" password="changeit" certificate-key-file="/usr/share/jboss7.0.2/standalone/configuration/certificates/keystore.jks" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="true" ca-certificate-file="/usr/share/jboss7.0.2/standalone/configuration/certificates/cacerts.jks" cipher-suite="AES+RSA"/>
```